# Error with using PowerShell and COM objects

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to work over PowerShell using the CERTENROLLLib and CERTCLIENTLib (COM objects).

```
$com = new-object -ComObject 'CERTCLIENTLib'
```

But i'm getting error: Cannot load COM type CERTCLIENTLib.
I think it is an issue with the namespace, but i don't have any idea what to do?

Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks like it might be a .NET to COM interop assembly and not a PROGID. If that is the case, you don't need the `-ComObject` parameter. If it is a .NET interop assembly you need to specify a class to create:

```
$com = new-object CERTCLIENTLib.CCertRequestClass
```

Comment: Well, it doesn't help.
I'm still getting error: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, you need to use the Add-Type cmdlet on Powershell 2.0.  If you're still on 1.0, use [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName().  However you need to find where the assembly lives (GAC, program files, download folder, etc).